# Solve $L^{-1}[\frac{1}{p(p^2+4)^2}]$

Tags: laplace-transform

Solve $L^{-1}[\frac{1}{p(p^2+4)^2}]$

I tried resolving it to partial fractions but could not do. Pls provide me any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us make use of three results:

- $$L^{-1}\left[\frac1{s^2+4}\right]=\frac12 \sin 2t$$
- $$L^{-1}\left[\frac1{s(s^2+4)}\right] $$ $$= \int_{0}^{t}\frac1{2} \sin 2t \, dt= \frac14 \left(1-\cos 2t\right)$$
- $$L^{-1} \left[\frac1{s(s^2+4)}\times \frac1{s^2+4} \right] $$ $$= \frac18 \int_{0}^{t} \left(1-\cos 2\tau\right) \sin 2(t-\tau) \, d\tau$$

which gives us the required answer:

> $$\frac1{16} \left(1-t\sin 2t - \cos 2t \right) $$

Comment: can we resolve this into partial fractions???? I have similar problems like $\frac{p}{(p^2+4)^3}$ etc

Comment: Why are you complicating matters? In problems like these, it is a good practice to search for the least time consuming method, which in this case is not by partial fractions.

Comment: actually i did not do convolution theorem.

Comment: Well if you insist, see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Partial+fraction+decomposition+of+1%2F(p(p%5E2%2B4)%5E2)

Comment: thank you. I am novice in this area.